# Not able to get id in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am sending ID through anchor tag in codeigniter

```
<a href='sectionEmpList/".$post_array['userSecId']."'>
```

and I am catching the value in controller like:

```
public function sectionEmpList($id){ 
    $secID = $id;
    echo $secID;  
}
```

but it shows following error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning Message: Missing argument 1 for
>   Dashboard::sectionEmpList() Filename: controllers/Dashboard.php Line
>   Number: 302 Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\mecon\application\controllers\Dashboard.php
>   Line: 302 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\mecon\index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

Can any one suggest what is the solution.

Comment: What's the router file look like? The `$id` isn't getting passed to this function is what the error is saying. So the url isn't being generated with an ID or the controller isn't handling it correctly.

Comment: URL getting the ID, but its not reaching controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to single quote.  Use as below

```
$url = $post_array['userSecId'];
<a href='sectionEmpList/'.$url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='sectionEmpList/'".$post_array['userSecId']."'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id to the view

```
public function sectionEmpList(){ 
    $data['secID'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
}
```

Then on view

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('your_controller/function/'. $secID);?>">
```

Autoload the [url helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url). And the session library.

You also may need to create a route.

Comment: I already have ID in my session, and I am passing that id from view to function in controller

Comment: You did not explain that in your question

Comment: rout i added like:

Comment: $route['sectionEmpList/(:any)'] = "dashboard/sectionEmpList";

Answer (score 0):

You're router file under `application/config/router.php` needs to look something like this (this is roughly, may be different depending on your set up.

```
$route['sectionEmpList/(:any)='] = 'YOURCONTROLLERHERE/sectionEmpList/$1';
```